# HTML tag specifically for storing arbitrary data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am loading a Razor [View](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs) via AJAX and putting the content into a div on a page.

If I want to send some arbitrary data from the view to our AJAX framework, is there a recommended HTML tag to do this with? A hidden field sounds like the wrong this to use for this. I could use an empty `div` with custom `data-` attributes, but again, a `div` sounds wrong.

My data isn't relevant to any element within this view, more related to the view itself.

Yes - this is simply a question of systematics and aesthetics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `data-*` attributes, and try to find and attach them to already existing related elements. This convention is also used by asp.net mvc framework itself - when link target needs to be loaded, `data-ajax-*` is attached to anchors. When you need to set update target of form submit, you attach `data-ajax-*` to form, so in most cases it is possible to find good candidate for it. If it is not possible in any particular case, I do not see problems using `body` instead.

Comment: I don't have a `body` - It's a partial view! It's relative to the "back" button, but in the layout, not this view. Perhaps I could send the back button across in the HTML as an `<input>` tag, then remove it and steal the data on the client side! Sounds dodgey though.

Comment: Not bad. If that's related to navigation, using anchor seems like the better option

Comment: My bad, yup, it's an `a`, not `input` (just looks like a button so I assumed it was...). I'm reading up on the `aside` tag to see if that would make sense. Sending the back link inside the `aside` tag.

Comment: It would just be nice if this existed so you can use a list of tags with a few attributes each instead of one huge list of data attributes on <body> or wherever. You could theoretically use <data> but it's a container tag which we really don't need (or want) here.